# Why isn't this closure working?

Tags: groovy

I have the following closure:

```
def deepSave = {
    it.attributes.each{it.save(validate: false)}
    it.elements.each{deepSave(it)}
    it.save(validate: false)
}
```

Which I call like this:

```
deepSave(someObject.rootElement)
```

This fails and the stacktrace is so long it fills up PowerShell's buffer so I cannot see what the cause is.

I made the method below to do the same thing I am attempting to do with the closure and it works fine.  Why isn't the closure working?

```
private def deepSave(def someElement) {
    for(attribute in someElement.attributes) {
        attribute.save(validate: false)
    }
    for(element in someElement.elements) {
        deepSave(element)
    }
    someElement.save(validate: false)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the validity of the scenario where you are doing the recursion but when you use `closure` for recursion the variable has to be pre-defined before it is tailored so that it can know about itself during recursion. For example:

```
def deepSave
deepSave = {
    it.attributes.each{it.save(validate: false)}
    it.elements.each{deepSave(it)}
    it.save(validate: false)
}
```

I could not figure out an exit strategy from the recursion, but I can add some more to it if you can elaborate on the context and add a breaking sample to run.

Comment: The recursion stops when there is no longer any child elements being called for "deepSave" - basically, it's just saving things until there's no more tree to recurse. I wonder if the only issue here was the missing predefined variable.